# How do you set the Long Press duration before the cross hair is displayyed for ShinobiCharts on Android?

Tags: android, shinobi

Right now it takes too long to select the bar, and its frustrating. I also have a bar graph, so you can only select a bar, which is unintuitive. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this query has two parts, so I'll cover each in turn. (Disclaimer - I work for ShinobiControls.)

1 - 'Right now it takes too long to select the bar, and its frustrating.' -

I am going to assume here that you are referring to the showing of the tool tip and crosshair on the ShinobiChart for Android. We have aligned our product's long press behaviour on that of Android. As such, our api currently does not expose any means of customising the long press duration (needed to show the crosshair). Whilst currently we have no plans to introduce this functionality, we are always interested to learn more about how our customers use our products, and what new features people want. As such, I'll register your interest in this feature and we will certainly give it consideration for the future.

2 - 'I also have a bar graph, so you can only select a bar, which is unintuitive.' -

I am making the assumption here that you are referring to the fact that for bar (and column) series one must long press inside a bar (or column) in order to show the crosshair and tooltip. This is unlike the behaviour of a line series on which a long press does not need to be directly on the series, for the crosshair and tooltip to be shown.

This behaviour was an explicit design decision which was made in order to achieve parity with our iOS charting product. This seems to be suitable for most of our clients but that said, having the option to customise this behaviour would be a nice feature. Again, whilst we have no immediate plans to implement such a feature, as with your previous point I will register your interest in this and we will certainly consider it for future development.

Thanks and kind regards,

Kai.

Thanks for the feedback and thanks for the upvote :-)
Rest assured I have added your feedback to our 'requested features' tracking system and it will be discussed in due course. Like I said before I cannot promise anything at this stage except that it certainly will be considered. Thanks again. Only with customer feedback like this can we continue to improve our products. Kind Regards, Kai.

Comment: Thanks. On iOS there exists a hack to set the long press time to 0, so the cross hair shows up on tap. I haven't seen a similar hack for Android. But I think that one in particular would make a great feature to have. I can understand that you have to long press on the bar graph to show crosshair. Again I'd like the option to have it consistent with line graphs. But from just watching people use it, these two together do result in an unintuitive way to show cross hair, specially on smaller graphs. Ask someone who isn't familiar with shinobi to use it on a 1/3 screen graph. They struggle